# Spring Session Remember Me

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

I have tried the spring session samples and it is really interesting.

i am trying to do the following , i am trying to plug spring session in the restful service where i want to different TTL for the session id's based on the request

For example, Client Consuming my restful service may have remember me Option On/OFF.

When remember me on i want to provide TTL as 90 days where as for the remember me off i want to set the TTL to 5 mins , how do we achieve this in spring session.

Also how do we manage(limiting) concurrent session for an user , is the concurrent session can be achieved by integrating with spring security or is the same capabilities provided in spring session.

Please suggest, any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by setting the [HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int timeInSeconds)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)). For example, after authenticating the user, you could do the following:

```
int someTime = getExpireBasedOnMyCriteria();
httpServletRequest.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(someTime);
```

Comment: Thank you Rob , i will try this and will keep you posted on the results

Comment: Can I use spring security remember me feature or would you recommend just setting long TTL?

Comment: You can use Spring Security's remember me feature, but when you have Spring Session there really should be the need. The main reason you would use remember me from Spring Security is to ensure the server doesn't have a ton of HTTP sessions in memory. Since Spring Session offloads this into another data store (i.e. Redis) the problem is already solved.